# Flutter bloc 8.x authentication not updating

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

Im experimenting and learning on a small project and im trying to implement an authentication workflow. Ive implemented everything and by printing my steps everything should just work fine. Im wondering why my `BlocBuilder` isn't going to update. The project is really small so I can provide you everything easy. Since im learning bloc, i appreciate every hint, approach and I want to thank you in advance.

terminal output when the app is starting:

```
flutter: building main.dart
flutter: AppLoaded()
flutter: user is NOT signed in
flutter: false
flutter: Transition { currentState: AuthInitial(), event: AppLoaded(), nextState: UnauthenticatedState() }
flutter: block says user is NOT authenticated
```

This is completely fine since im checking at the beginning if there is any user data valid. Now when I press on the `Login Textbutton` in my `home.dart` my Blocbuilder should show that im logged in, but it doesnt. This is the terminal output:

```
flutter: AppLoaded()
flutter: signed id with credentials: User{id: 1, socketId: 123, userName: Logged in User}
flutter: user is signed in
flutter: true
flutter: currentuser is not empty: User{id: 1, socketId: 123, userName: Logged in User}
flutter: Transition { currentState: AuthInitial(), event: AppLoaded(), nextState: AuthenticatedState() }
flutter: block says user is authenticated
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:fl_auth/bloc/auth/auth_bloc.dart';
import 'package:fl_auth/repositories/user_repository.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import 'bloc/bloc_observer.dart';
import 'home.dart';
import 'models/auth.dart';

void main() {
  BlocOverrides.runZoned(
    () {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    },
    blocObserver: SimpleBlocObserver(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Auth _auth = Auth.instance;
    UserRepository _userRepository = UserRepository(auth: _auth);
    print('building main.dart');

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) =>
            AuthBloc(userRepository: _userRepository)..add(AppLoaded()),
        child: Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**home.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import 'bloc/auth/auth_bloc.dart';
import 'models/auth.dart';
import 'repositories/user_repository.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Auth _auth = Auth.instance;
    UserRepository _userRepository = UserRepository(auth: _auth);
    AuthBloc authBloc = AuthBloc(userRepository: _userRepository);
    return Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox(
            height: 500,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  child: BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
                      builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is UnauthenticatedState) {
                      return Center(child: Text('User is unauthenticated'));
                    } else if (state is AuthenticatedState) {
                      return Center(child: Text('YEAH logged in!'));
                    } else {
                      return Center(child: Text('something went wrong'));
                    }
                  }),
                ),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () => {
                          authBloc.userRepository.signIn(),
                          authBloc.add(AppLoaded())
                        },
                    child: Text('Login')),
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

**auth_event.dart**

```
part of 'auth_bloc.dart';

abstract class AuthEvent extends Equatable {
  const AuthEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AppLoaded extends AuthEvent {}
```

**auth_state.dart**

```
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, sort_constructors_first
part of 'auth_bloc.dart';

abstract class AuthState extends Equatable {
  const AuthState();
  
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AuthInitial extends AuthState {}
class AuthenticatedState extends AuthState {
  User user;
  AuthenticatedState({
    required this.user,
  });
}
class UnauthenticatedState extends AuthState {}
```

**auth.bloc**

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:fl_auth/repositories/user_repository.dart';

import '../../models/user.dart';

part 'auth_event.dart';
part 'auth_state.dart';

class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  UserRepository userRepository;
  AuthBloc({required this.userRepository}) : super(AuthInitial()) {
    on<AppLoaded>((event, emit) async {
      try {
        var isSignedIn = await userRepository.isSignedIn();
        print(isSignedIn);
        if (isSignedIn) {
          var user = await userRepository.getCurrentUser();
          emit(AuthenticatedState(user: user));
          print('block says user is authenticated');
        } else {
          emit(UnauthenticatedState());
          print('block says user is NOT authenticated');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        emit(UnauthenticatedState());
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**user_repository.dart**

```
import 'package:fl_auth/models/user.dart';

import '../models/auth.dart';

class UserRepository {
  Auth auth = Auth.instance;

  UserRepository({required this.auth});

  // sign in with username
  //TODO: change hardcoded username to email and passwort later on
  Future<User> signIn() async {
    try{
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      var credentials = User(id: 1, socketId: '123', userName: 'Logged in User');
      print('signed id with credentials: ${auth.currentUser}');
      auth.currentUser = credentials;
      return auth.currentUser;
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      throw e;
    }
  }

  // check signed in status
  Future<bool> isSignedIn() async {
    try{
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      var currentUser = auth.currentUser;
      if(currentUser.isNotEmpty){
        print('user is signed in');
        return true;
      } else {
        print('user is NOT signed in');
        return false;
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      throw e;
    }
  }

  // get user
  Future<User> getCurrentUser() async {
    try{
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      var currentUser = auth.currentUser;
      if(currentUser.isNotEmpty){
        print('currentuser is not empty: $currentUser');
        return currentUser;
      } else {
        var message = 'User is empty';
        print('currentuser IS empty: $currentUser');
        throw message;
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

**auth.dart**

```
import 'user.dart';

class Auth {
  /// private constructor
  Auth._();
  /// the one and only instance of this singleton
  static final instance = Auth._();
  //ChatBloc chatBloc = ChatBloc(DatabaseApi.db);
  
  // Create a User instance. Actually it would be better if this is empty so I can notice if a user is valid or not and can react by checking if the user has values and
  // if not log the user out later on
  User currentUser = User.empty;
}
```

**user.dart**
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

```
/// {@template user}
/// User model
///
/// [User.empty] represents an unauthenticated user.
/// {@endtemplate}
class User extends Equatable {
  /// {@macro user}
  const User({
    required this.id,
    this.socketId,
    this.userName,
  });

  /// The current user's scoket id.
  final String? socketId;

  /// The current user's id.
  final int id;

  /// The current user's name (display name).
  final String? userName;

  /// Empty user which represents an unauthenticated user.
  static const empty = User(id: 0);

  /// Convenience getter to determine whether the current user is empty.
  bool get isEmpty => this == User.empty;

  /// Convenience getter to determine whether the current user is not empty.
  bool get isNotEmpty => this != User.empty;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [id, socketId, userName];


  // Convert a user into a Map. The keys must correspond to the names of the
  // columns in the database.
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'socketId': socketId,
      'userName': userName,
    };
  }

   factory User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return User(
      id: map['id'] as int,
      socketId: map['socketId'] as String,
      userName: map['userName'] as String,
    );
  }

  // Implement toString to make it easier to see information about
  // each user when using the print statement.
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'User{id: $id, socketId: $socketId, userName: $userName}';
  }
}
```

Comment: Where Is BlocListener? As I see that you have implemented bloc Currently but UI is not updating because you haven't used BlocListner in Home.dart

Comment: Im not using any.. Isnt blocbuilder also listening to state changes? and how would the implementation look like?

Comment: If Possible can you please share your Git link of this project.

Comment: yes, here is the link https://github.com/md186/flutter_bloc_authentication_excercise

Comment: it says on the documentation here: https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/ blocprovider: If the bloc parameter is omitted, BlocBuilder will automatically perform a lookup using BlocProvider and the current BuildContext. so it should work fine in my understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is In your OnTap Function you can call Event like this. I have checked and It's working as expected.

```
 TextButton(
                    onPressed: () => {
                          authBloc.userRepository.signIn(),
                          context.read<AuthBloc>().add(AppLoaded())
                         
                        },
                    child: const Text('Login')),
```

Comment: alright, thank you for your answer, could you explain me more in detail why it is working with this approach, also another question, i have to create Auth _auth = Auth.instance;
    UserRepository _userRepository = UserRepository(auth: _auth); in every file where i have to do something, is this fine initializing it multiple times or do i run in some issues?